# A big kid plays with other kids while everyone else is guessing about a kid. No I'm not kidding at all!

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

A little while ago my friends had an elaborate baby shower to celebrate my friend's first pregnancy.  I admit that I'm a giant man-child who loves playing with kids more then pretending to be an adult so other then giving my best wishes to the mommy to be, and getting to try to feel the baby kick real quick, I was mostly relegated to babysitting the children of parents attending the shower.

At one point during the shower I happened to come downstairs right as all the guests were writing down their guess for the sex of the baby.  Those that guessed correctly would be entered into a small raffle at the end of the party.  The kids were all occupied with games upstairs, with the only child young enough that they couldn't be trusted unsupervised for a few minutes having tagged along with me anyways.  I figured I had the time to quickly put my name in the raffle before returning to my babysitting duties.

Now I had never asked, or been told, the sex of the baby at any point during the pregnancy.  Still, despite this fact, I decided I probably shouldn't join the raffle.  My reason was partially due to how well acquainted I was with the baby's biological fathers.  Can you tell me why I didn't make a guess?

I believe this puzzle should be solvable without hints, but below are included to keep puzzle from being too open ended.

> No, that wasn't a typo.

> I had an unfair advantage in the raffle

> It wasn't just that I knew certain individuals so well, but that it put me in the position I could become aware of other facts that weren't common knowledge.

slightly bigger spoilers:

> Sometimes the best lies are the ones that are entirely true...

> Why would a good friend never be curious enough to ask about the sex of their friend's child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like [Bjorn Eriksson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/114371/21402) said, one of the parents is a trans male--thus why the baby can have biological fathers, plural. Your friends used in vitro fertilization and asked a mutual friend to be the surrogate mother. I believe this third friend, who is pregnant for the first time, is the one referred to as "the mommy to be".
>
>  Also, the biological parents asked their IVF clinic to do [preimplantation genetic diagnosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_selection#IVF/PGD_technique) to select an embryo of a particular sex. They told you about these plans before going through with the procedure.
>
>  Thus, you're technically telling the truth when you say "I had never asked, or been told, the sex of the baby at any point *during the pregnancy*." You weren't told during the pregnancy; you were told *before* the pregnancy!

Answer (score 4):

> You are a sonographer and happened to be the technician that treated your friends (hence discovered the sex of their child). Though, I'm unsure how this would be related to the first and final hint, so perhaps this isn't what you were looking for. I guess the final hint could be addressed by the fact that you already knew the sex of the child so you had no incentive to ask - still unsure about the first hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think that

> One of the parents is a trans male. He kept his ovaries when he transitioned, or has decided to not do the switch, but is not willing to tell everyone about it.

> Since you know this, the gender reveal becomes a bit of a non-issue. Who knows what the true gender of the baby will turn out to be eventually. It will take years before it can tell us anyway.

Comment: I initially had the same idea but the fact that dsollen rot13(fcrpvsvpnyyl fgngrq gung vg jnf n "frk erirny") diverted my thoughts

Comment: You're notice I said they were guessing about the sex not gender.  One can safely guess sex of a child at birth without making any presumptions about gender.

Comment: I should say that you're first idea is on the right track.  However look at all the people I mentioned in the story and you will see you're not accounting for all of the individuals yet.

Answer (score 0):

New opinion

> There's a pregnant woman attending the raffle, but the guests aren't guessing her baby's sex. They're guessing the homosexual couple adopted child's sex. And as one of the fathers, you know it already. I found this at the first hint (nice one), and then clicked the others to confirm.

What led me to it

> "I happened to come downstairs right as all the guests were writing down their guess for the sex of the baby." All the guests, which would mean you're not a guest, but one of the hosts.

> "Now I had never asked, or been told, the sex of the baby at any point during the pregnancy." Because there was no pregnancy involved, and you didn't pick your new child during your friend's pregnancy.

First guess

> You're one of the fathers, in a homosexual couple. The child is from a surrogate mother. I think it follows the original plot pretty well. You never mentionned being invited, and I guess you are pretty well acquainted with the fathers in that case.